# Mapbox studio: how to change background image of map based zoom level?

Tags: mapbox

I am getting started on mapbox studio. I want to be able to change the background image based on the zoom level - so far default way to set image is:

```
Map {
background-color: @land;
background-image:url(pattern/3.png) 
}
```

I have tried adding zoom level conditions as follow.

```
Map {
background-color: @land;
   [zoom>=5] {background-image:url(pattern/2.jpg);}
   [zoom<=5] { background-image:url(pattern/3.png);}
}
```

appreciate if you can share any tips or point to resource and methods I can read.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties in the Map object are global properties that cannot be filtered or changed by zoom level. In order to have different backgrounds at different zoom levels you will need to create a custom polygon layer to act as your background, but with more flexible styling. You would use `polygon-pattern-file` on this layer instead of `background-image`.

See the [source quickstart tutorial](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio/source-quickstart/) for info about creating a custom source layer and adding it to your style project. You can use the 'bounding box' file [from Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/10m-graticules/) for this; it is a single polygon that covers the entire map.